# Is this a mem leak in main?

Tags: c++, memory

this is my code,

```
class MyClass
{
...
};

int main(){

MyClass class = new MyClass;
/*if i do this,
delete class;
i receive a seg fault*/

return 0;
}
```

Is this a mem leak?If yes how can i fix it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

That won't even *compile* since you're using the `class` keyword as a variable, so you won't get a segfault.

If you fixed that problem (and possibly several others that I think are there but couldn't be bothered looking up), I wouldn't expect it to segfault unless there was a serious problem in your constructor or destructor.

Get your code to compile first, then we can sort out any logic errors.

Comment: It's probably stack corruption but since it crashes on the destructor, he thinks it's related to the destructor.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the fact that class cannot be used as a variable name, the new operator in C++ will return a pointer to an object of type MyClass. The statment should be:

```
MyClass *objectPtr = new MyClass;
```

If you then fail to delete it, it will still exist in memory until the program finishes, and therefore count as a leak (presumably).

Comment: Didn't see that one itiatially - good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get the variable name right and make it a `MyClass *`, yes that is a memory leak. Because you have acquired memory through a call to `new` but you haven't given the memory back.

The solution is to `delete` the pointer when you are done using it.

So for example:

```
MyClass *c = new MyClass;
...
delete c;
```

Note that if you have `new`ed an array, you need to free it like this:

```
MyClass *c_arr = new MyClass[10];
...
delete[] c_arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, yes it is.  Allocating with new, without deleting, is a memory leak.  Ironically however, that memory leak is the mildest problem with this code snippet, and it won't even matter since the program terminates the moment it's 'leaked'.

I am assuming this is 'psuedo-code', so I won't point out the compile errors.  But it's helpful to avoid psuedo-code, since it does not allow people to see issues you wouldn't have included in the snippet otherwise.

If `delete` causes a segfault, which I think is your real question, then your problem could be a host of other things besides a memory leak.  Memory leaks in general do not cause immediate segfaults, they must exhaust the available pool of memory first.  If that is your question, it may help to include the code MyClass uses, especially for the destructor.